# Design a layout at middle of screen android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design a layout like the third screen below.

[image]

But I have no idea how to make it. And how to keep same position of that in any screen size?

Any example is good for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use my below code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"android:background="#aaabca"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="19:08"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0 Sms"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="0 Calls"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="WEDNESDAY \nOCTOBER 15"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's good but in big screen the height seem so small.
Anyway it's helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. For that you can use two different folders.              layout-sw1200 and layout